# Passing arguments to Django CBV for queryset

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to figure out how can I pass arguments from a generic view where a user submits a form to a cbv template view.

My first generic view is as such:

```
def homepage(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SearchForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form_data = form.cleaned_data
            return redirect('filtered', city=form_data['city'], category=form_data['category'])

    else:
        form = SearchForm()
   return render(request, 'index.html', context={'form': form})
```

What Im trying to achieve is that when a user choses a city and a category then he gets submitted to a homepage that is a TemplateView where there's a queryset based on objects that are in the selected city and of selected category.

```
class ListAd(ListView):
    model = Ad
    template_name = 'filtered'
    queryset =  # here Im expecting to make a query based on the 'city' and 'category' chosen in previous view
```

How to pass the city and category arguments to the `ListAd` view so I can use them in the queryset? This is the ursl.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('list_new/<city>/<category>/', views.ListAd.as_view(), name='filtered'),

]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this should works.

```
class ListAd(ListView):
    model = Ad
    template_name = 'filtered'
    queryset = Ad.objects.all()
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(ListAd, self).get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset.filter(city=self.kwargs["city"], category=self.kwargs["category"])
        return queryset
```